# Spring Security (Java Config): Using antmatchers for same URL with differing HTTP methods

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to restrict GET access to a URL for one role, and POST access to the same URL for another role as seen below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("readuser").password("password").roles("USER", "READ").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "READ", "WRITE");
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin().permitAll().and()
            .logout().permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/foo").hasRole("READ")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/foo").hasRole("WRITE")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic();
```

When I try a GET (or a POST) with my readuser account, I get an access denied error; but when I try either with the admin account, it can do both.

However, when I remove the line `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/foo").hasRole("WRITE")` then my readuser account can properly hit /api/foo with a GET request.

How can I make Spring Security allow both of these restrictions?

**UPDATE - including relevant spring security debug log information**

Here are the relevant logs when attempting with readuser:

```
************************************************************

Request received for GET '/api/foo?id=foo':

Request(GET //localhost:8089/api/foo?id=foo)@b4603eb

servletPath:/api/foo
pathInfo:null
headers:
Authorization: Basic cnVudXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
Cookie: JSESSIONID=node0fe3b0i44a5sbpohi6jq6dkkw0.node0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/3.0.11-hotfix.2
Connection: keep-alive
Postman-Token: 99a23213-6cf8-4686-9886-7f9c2de13c6f
Host: localhost:8089
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************
.
.
.
2017-05-08 11:31:27.817 DEBUG 5812 --- [p1731685294-106] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/foo'; against 'GET'
2017-05-08 11:31:27.817 DEBUG 5812 --- [p1731685294-106] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/foo'; against '/api/foo'
2017-05-08 11:31:27.817 DEBUG 5812 --- [p1731685294-106] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/foo?id=foo; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_WRITE')]
2017-05-08 11:31:27.818 DEBUG 5812 --- [p1731685294-106] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@a38eb23d: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@5c7268d6: Username: readuser; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_READ,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_READ, ROLE_USER
2017-05-08 11:31:27.818 DEBUG 5812 --- [p1731685294-106] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@7b20c046, returned: -1
2017-05-08 11:31:27.819 DEBUG 5812 --- [p1731685294-106] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
.
.
.
2017-05-08 11:31:27.823 DEBUG 5812 --- [p1731685294-106] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: I just mocked up a spring boot app with this config and seems to work properly for me.  I can hit `GET` with readuser but get access denied for `POST` as expected.  With admin I'm able to hit both.  Might be something with the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong `HttpMethod` class.

[`javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod#GET`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/HttpMethod.html#GET) returns a `String` and therefore you use [`antMatchers(String... antPatterns)`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#antMatchers-java.lang.String...-) instead of [`antMatchers(HttpMethod method, String... antPatterns)`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#antMatchers-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-java.lang.String...-) in your Spring Security configuration.

With that configuration Spring Security checks against the URL patterns `GET` and `/api/foo` (both for all HTTP methods), see your log:

> ```
> 2017-05-08 11:31:27.817 DEBUG 5812 --- [p1731685294-106] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/foo'; against 'GET' 
> 2017-05-08 11:31:27.817 DEBUG 5812 --- [p1731685294-106] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/foo'; against '/api/foo'
> ```

You have to use [`org.springframework.http.HttpMethod#GET`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpMethod.html#GET), which returns a `HttpMethod` object.